# how to insert into two tables from vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, insert

i want to insert two values into two tables of a sql database which i had created. In my vb.net code my problem is if i insert it get insterted but only in one table else sometimes it's not getting inside.

here is my code which i had used:

```
    c = TextBox1.Text
    sh = TextBox2.Text
    ph = Val(TextBox3.Text)
    ad = RichTextBox1.Text
    ob = Val(TextBox4.Text)
    con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\SHOPPROJECT\SHOPPROJECT\shop.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
    con.Open()

    str1 = " INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('" & c & " ' , '" & sh & "' ," & ph & ",'" & ad & "' ,'" & TextBox5.Text & "' ) "

    str2 = "INSERT INTO BALANCE VALUES ('" & c & "', " & ob & ")"

    cmd = New SqlCommand

    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = str1
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.CommandText = str2
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("ITEM IS INSERTED", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "CUSTOMER ADDED")
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox2.Clear()
    TextBox3.Clear()
    TextBox4.Clear()
    TextBox5.Clear()
    RichTextBox1.Clear()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually do it in a single command and even wrap it in a transaction like this:

```
str1 = "begin tran; "
str1 &= "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('" & c & " ' , '" & sh & "' ," & ph & ",'" & ad & "' ,'" & TextBox5.Text & "' ); "
str1 &= "INSERT INTO BALANCE VALUES ('" & c & "', " & ob & "); "
str1 &= "commit tran; "

cmd = New SqlCommand
cmd.Connection = con
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.CommandText = str1
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Next you need to use try/catch on a SqlServerException to see what is going wrong. Something like:

```
try
    ' all your sql code
catch (sqlex as SqlException)
    MessageBox.Show(sqlex.Message)
```

Also read up on SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use different string variable to insert the values. You can do it like this:

```
str1 = " INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('" & c & " ' , '" & sh & "' ," & ph & ",'" & ad & "' ,'" & TextBox5.Text & "' );"
str1 & = "INSERT INTO BALANCE VALUES ('" & c & "', " & ob & ")"

cmd = New SqlCommand

    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = str1
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: hey it shows a erroe under the str1& it says type character '&' does not match the declared datatype string string

Comment: sorry i  had not putten space

Comment: there is a space between str1 and &