# Are there ways to add 2 Table when using the INSERT statement in query builder?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, insert, query-builder

It seems like the query builder in vb only allow 1 table to use the INSERT statement, so are there any way add more than 1?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to wrap them all into one command call.  Here is an example of what I think you are looking for.

[how to insert into two tables from vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356162/how-to-insert-into-two-tables-from-vb-net)

Comment: I've not learn command call yet so I ain't confident bout it, Are there any other solution beside the command call?

Comment: How are you currently connecting to sql and the table currently?  I am still new to using LINQ, but a bunch of my coworkers are build on using LINQ to query SQLServer. If you decide to look into the LINQ option here are some examples that I have found pretty helpful. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688088

Answer (score 0):

```
Using con As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("YourConnection string")
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    Dim expression As String = "Parameter value"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.CommandText = "Your Stored Procedure"
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Your Parameter Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = expression
    cmd.Connection = con
    Using dr As IDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If dr.Read() Then
        End If
    End Using
End Using
```